# Are these polynomials gamma-nonnegative?

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials

Let $d$ be a positive integer and define $\binom{n}{k}_d=\prod_{j=0}^{d-1}\frac{\binom{n+j}{k}}{\binom{k+j}{k}}$.
Consider the polynomials $$p_{n}^{(d)}(x)=\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{n}{j}_d x^j.$$
For $d=2$ these are the Narayana polynomials which are gamma-nonnegative.

Computer experiments suggest that all polynomials $p_{n}^{(d)}(x)$ are gamma-nonnegative. This means that there are positive integers  $\gamma_j$ such that $ p_{n}^{(d)}(x)=\sum\gamma_j x^j (1+x)^{n-2j}.$

Any idea how to prove this?

Comment: Observation: $\binom{n}{k}_d$ is the number of plane partitions which fit in a $k\times (n-k) \times d$ box (see [formula for $N_1(r,s,t)$ here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_partition#Generating_function_of_plane_partitions)).

Comment: @Mike Earnest: Thank you for this interesting combinatorial interpretation!